# Form submission without parameter name

Tags: html, forms

```
<form action="/foo">
        <input type="text" name="q">
        <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

In the previous HTML, if the user types in 'bar' and clicks the button it would submit to `example.com/foo?q=bar`.
How can I make it go to `example.com/foo/bar`? 
I can easily do it with JS but I'm trying to stick to HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this in HTML, you need a programming language.

Have something on the server process the form an issue an HTTP 301 response with a `Location` header.

You could enhance that by use the form's `submit` event to prevent the default action and set `location` in JS.

Comment: Thanks, I just did it with some simple JS. Not having a native HTML element be able to create what today seems to be the best-practice for good URL schemes is surprising.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the value of the `action` attribute with HTML only. You need to use JS or any other scripting language.